# Processing error: Function init() does not exist

Tags: java

**MAIN CLASS:**

```
Player thePlayer = new Player();
Guard theGuard = new Guard();

void setup() {
  size(1000, 500);
  theGuard.init();
  thePlayer.init();
}

void updateGame() {
  thePlayer.update();
}

void drawGame() {
  background(0);
  thePlayer.draw();

  fill(color(255, 255, 255));
  text("Score:" + score, 10, 20);
}

void draw() {
  fill (255, 255, 255);
  rect(0, 401, 1000, 100);
  noFill();

  updateGame();
  drawGame();
}
```

**GUARD CLASS**

```
class Guard {
  float x, y;
  float vx, vy;
  float fillColor;
  float diameter;
}

void init() {

}

void update() {
  if (x == (irandom(width)-100)) 
    vx = 3;

  if (x == (irandom(width)+100)) 
    vx = -3;

  x += vx;
  y += vy;
}

void draw() {
  fill(fillColor);
  rect(x, y, diameter, diameter);
}
```

**PLAYER CLASS**

```
class Player {
  float x, y;
  float vx, vy;
  float fillColor;
  float playerHeight, playerWidth;
  float jumpTime;
  boolean isJumping;
}

void init() {
  playerHeight = 20;
  playerWidth = 20;
  fillColor = color(255, 255, 255);
  jumpTime = 200;
  isJumping = false;

  x = 100;
  y = 400;

  vx = 0;
  vy = 0;
}

void update() {
  if (keyPressed) {
    if (keyCode == LEFT) vx = -2;
    if (keyCode == RIGHT) vx = 2;
    if (keyCode == UP) isJumping = true;
    if (keyCode == DOWN) playerHeight = 10;
  }
  else {
    vx = 0;
    vy = 0;
  }

  if (isJumping == true) {
    vy = -2;
  }
  else {
    vy -= 0.1;
  }

  if (y == 100)
    vy = 0;

  x += vx;
  y += vy;
}

void draw() {
  fill(fillColor);
  ellipse(x, y, playerWidth, playerHeight);
}
```

i wrote it in Processing (JAVA). But i don't know why my code doesnt work. When i try to launch the game, it gives the error: "The function init() does not exist". This function is used in line 6/7 from the main class. Is there a way to create this function or something?

Comment: Are all your classes in the same package? The method might not be visible.

Comment: In future note and give the line number the compiler is specifically saying.

Comment: pu the methods inside he class buddy as `class Foo{ void bar(){}}` your methods are not belong to `Guard` and `Player` classes :)

Answer (score 1):

Note where the brackets defining the class and method are here. `Guard` does not have an `init()`

```
class Guard {
  ...
}

void init() {

}
```

Certainly should define `init` in `Guard`. Probably should define `Guard` in it's own file, Guard.java

Comment: Note there is no such thing as a function in Java. *All* methods must be members of a class. `init` is not the only method that doesn't exist here.

Comment: Guard is probably an inner class if they got that far with the compiler. And another thing, Java has constructors.